# Adding list to column that does not scroll

Tags: dart, flutter

So I have my UI being built inside of a ListView which scrolls and is fine, I am going to have many instances of the same widget towards the bottom, how can I add these widgets without placing them inside another ListView? If I do that the user can scroll the internal one instead of the parent.

I will be pulling the number of `ContestBar` widgets from a database that will also contain information for each. There has to be a way to dynamically populate these without putting them inside a list view, since I want the whole screen to scroll not just the `ContestBar` widgets.

Here is the code...

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _onRefresh,
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 150.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          ProfileBar(
            displayName: 'Zach S.',
            points: 1324,
            balance: 256.15,
            initials: 'ZS',
          ),
          Container(
            height: 64.0,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: const Border(bottom: const BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black12)),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 16.0),
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: List<Padding>.generate(sortChipNames.length, (int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                  child: ChoiceChip(
                    label: Text(sortChipNames[index]),
                    selected: _selectedChips.contains(index),
                    onSelected: (bool selected) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedChips.contains(index) ? _selectedChips.remove(index)
                                                       : _selectedChips.add(index);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
          // Here is the instance of the same widget, this will eventually come from a database and have way more than 5.
          ContestBar(),
          ContestBar(),
          ContestBar(),
          ContestBar(),
          ContestBar(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was able to get it to work by adding a `Flex` widget, set the `direction` property to `Axis.vertical` and set the `children` to the List of `ContestBar` widgets. The code is below.

The List

```
final List<ContestBar> testContests = <ContestBar>[
  ContestBar(),
  ContestBar(),
  ContestBar(),
  ContestBar(),
  ContestBar(),
];
```

The widget

```
Flex(
  direction: Axis.vertical,
  children: testContests,
),
```